Why is the Greek in website Bible Hub different to others?
The website Open Bible has:

Matthew 27:8 ► Greek Texts
Nestle Greek New Testament 1904
διὸ ἐκλήθη ὁ ἀγρὸς ἐκεῖνος Ἀγρὸς
αἵματος ἕως τῆς σήμερον.
Scrivener's Textus Receptus 1894
διὸ ἐκλήθη ὁ ἀγρὸς ἐκεῖνος ἀγρὸς αἵματος, ἕως τῆς σήμερον.

Bible Hub has:

διὸ ἀγρὸς ἐκλήθη Ἀγρὸς αἵματος ἕως σήμερον

Bible Hub has omitted ὁ ἐκεῖνος τῆς in Matthew 27:8.
Why is the Greek in website Bible Hub different to others?

Unless I am mistaken, Biblehub are using Nestle 1904 〈NE〉
Eberhard Nestle, Η ΚΑΙΝΗ ΔΙΑΘΗΚΗ. Text with Critical Apparatus. (British and Foreign Bible Society, 1904). as their Greek text for their interlinear comparison. See beneath the Greek text of Matthew 1:1. But they also refer to 'variants' in an unclear way.

Thank you. Are you suggesting Bible Hub is unreliable?

No, I am just unclear as to what they are conveying about 'variants'. I exclusively use Stephens 1550 (Textus Receptus) myself.

There are about 20 different "accepted" texts of the NT - all slightly different.
